# Voltage supervisory circuit selection

Tags: digital-logic, undervoltage

I am trying to understand how to choose a suitable voltage supervisor IC for a given project. I have two questions:

1. if I have a digital IC, in its datasheet there is information about the minimum power supply voltage needed for proper behavior. From what the manufacturer obtained those numbers? Is it based on the statistical data to ICs made with the respective technologies? If the voltage has a lower value, what happens then - is the behavior of the IC undefined?
2. (related to the topic): suppose I have a digital circuit (e.g. microcontroller) for which the manufacturer specified the minimum supply voltage to be equal to 1.7V. I want to choose an external supervisor IC. The thing that I cannot understand is: how to choose the minimum voltage for which the supervisor's operation is defined? E.g. I found one for which the minimum supply voltage needed for proper behavior is 1.1V and the threshold voltage is 1.7V - I understand that within the range 1.1V - 1.7V that IC will put the microcontroller under RESET, but what if my supply falls lower than 1.1V?

Comment: Concerning your second question: almost no part will work with a Vcc of 1.1V. For example, the drop voltage of a typical silicon diode is already 0.7V. As you might guess, you can be considered safe because your micro controller won't work anyway at a such low voltage.

Answer (score 1):

1. I've seen cases where people undervoltage (or overclock for a given voltage) to get more performance per power. So manufacturers tend to have a safety margin on wether an IC should work or not at a given voltage. I would not expect a detailed statistical report of functioning outside of the recommended values though. Even if you are be able to achieve operation on a given batch at lower voltage, that does not guarantee future operation of other batches of ICs.
2. Even though an MCU (as you mentioned) might state 1.7V minimum working voltage, it will probably not have all the performance it has at "ideal" voltage (say 3.3V or 5V). It might need to work with a lower frequency, for example. I'd expect the detection circuits to work from the threshold (1.1V on your example) all the way to 0V.

You can then either set a brownout threshold to turn off the MCU (most have this feature buit in) or as you mentioned build an external supervisor circuit.

[image: MSP430 freq vs voltage]

Answer (score 0):

1. The minimum voltage is based on design data. During design the manufacturer will have to make certain decisions such as the basic technology (FET or BJT), analog / digital, input impedance, output drive capability, internal circuit complexity and compatibility with other standard devices and power supplies. All of these will determine the operating voltage range.
2. If possible you should let the micro-controller look after the voltage monitoring itself through the device's built-in under-voltage detection (if it has any) or by monitoring the battery voltage (usually through a divider) on an analog input. This will help reduce component count. With falling battery voltage your circuit and program can detect this and shut down the outputs in an orderly fashion before the micro abruptly shuts itself down. Beware of creating a continuous stop / start cycle: i.e., battery voltage falls, you switch off the outputs which causes the voltage to rise a little, micro starts up, outputs turn on, battery voltage falls ...